# How does wall thickness affect millimeter wave penetration in metals?

Tags: electromagnetism

As far as millimeter electromagnetic waves are concerned, do they penetrate through very thin layer of metal (micrometers)?

What is the law that relate wall-thickness, frequency and penetration depth of electromagnetic waves in metals?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The intensity of an electromagnetic wave decays inside a conductor according to the Beer-Lambert law
$$ I(z) = I_0e^{-\alpha z},$$
where $z$ is measured from the surface normal to the surface. The penetration depth is
given by $\alpha^{-1}$. In metals, $2/\alpha$ is identical with the skin-depth.
The skin depth is given by
$$ \delta = \sqrt{\frac{2\rho}{\omega\mu}}\sqrt{\sqrt{1+(\rho\omega\epsilon)^2}+\rho\omega\epsilon},$$
where $\rho$ is the resistivity of the metal, $\omega$ is the angular frequency of the wave, $\epsilon=\epsilon_0\epsilon_\mathrm{r}$ with the permittivity of vacuum $\epsilon_0$ and the relative permittivity of the material $\epsilon_\mathrm{r}$, $\mu=\mu_0\mu_\mathrm{r}$ with the permeability of vacuum $\mu_0$ and the relative magnetic permeability $\mu_\mathrm{r}$ of the material.